# Hazelcast calls loadAll for each collection key from loadAllKeys

Tags: hazelcast

why loadAll called for each key? now i use loadAll as load

```
@Override
public Map<Integer, Office> loadAll(Collection<Integer> keys) {
    log.debug("---------OfficeLoader::loadAll:" + keys);
    Office office = officeRepository.find(keys.iterator().next());        
    Map<Integer, Office> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put(office.getId(),office);
    return result;
}
```

why don't you use load for that case instead? and loadAll for loading all entries in one request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should not be called for each key, but i guess you don't have much keys.

How it works is: imagine you have 271 partitions and 2710 records and lets assume all the records are equally spread among the partitions.

Then you get a single call to loadAllKeys() and then you get 271 calls to loadAll(keys) where each 'keys' contains 10 keys for that particular partition to load.

Comment: I have 1 million records in my db for a mysql table and i jsut want to load 10000 of them. I tried using LoadAll with a collection key which has 10000 keys in it. But it loads all 1 million records instead. why so Set<Long> keySet = new HashSet<Long>();
        for(long i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
         keySet.add(i);
        }
       map.loadAll(keySet,true);